# app porting from Android to iPhone

Tags: android, ios, cordova

I'm porting an app created with Phonegap/Cordova 2.3.0 in iOS (xcode 5).
I created the project helloword with this [tutorial](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.3.0/guide_getting-started_ios_index.md.html), and I replaced the entire "www" folder and config.xml. When I start the project I can see only the classic phonegap launchimage and a simply grey view; it seems that index.js is called. 
If I do it in index.js I see this alert.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     alert("HELLO");
}
```

Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Did you add cordova.js corresponding to each platform?

Comment: inside there is a file called "cordova-2.3.0.js"

Comment: different cordova-2.3.0.js should be used different platforms. Open cordova-2.3.0.js. Platform name is written at the top

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cordova.js file is different from each platform. you can't copy and paste it.

You should run

```
cordova build android
```

from your project folder.

check the documentation here [Cordova](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.0.0/guide_cli_index.md.html)

---

Edit :

If you follow the instruction on the previous link, you should run

```
cordova platform add ios
```

This command will copy your www content to project folder/platform/ios

Then you can built it using

```
cordova build iOS
```

This command will add your plugins if any, generate config files...

You can finally use xcode to test your application.

You can try to follow these instruction : [Cordova platform ios](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.0.0/guide_platforms_ios_index.md.html#iOS%20Platform%20Guide)

Hope it helps

Comment: in my android project with phonegap I have a cordova-2.3.0.js that I put inside the ios project

Comment: the files have the same name but not the same content.

Comment: and to run the project? Can I run it with the classi xcode "play button"?

Comment: Sorry, I tought you already had an iOS project and you wanted to have the same for android, let me edit my answer

Comment: ahhahahha no no, I have an Andriod project and I want porting it to iOS

Comment: then, I try this link that if for 2.3.0 version [link](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.3.0/guide_command-line_index.md.html), and after the build is ok but when I do run I have this error message: _Error: ios-sim was not found. Please download, build and install version 1.4 or greater from https://github.com/phonegap/ios-sim into your path. Or "brew install ios-sim" using homebrew: http://mxcl.github.com/homebrew/_

Comment: It looks like this plugin has not been deployed to your new platform.
You can remove it and reinstall it : `cordova plugin ls`
`cordova plugin rm pluginname`
and reinstall it.

Comment: Use `$(function() {
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);            
});` `function ondeviceready() {
     alert("HELLO");
}`

Comment: what this line should do?

Comment: it waits that phone gap is ready to be used, it's not the same than document.ready